# If you want to say "a person with tanlines" , which of these would be more accurate: 日焼けあとが残っている人, 日焼けあとが残る人 or 日焼けあとがある人?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Are all three acceptable or do they mean different things?

> 日焼けあとが残っている人
>
> 日焼けあとが残る人
>
> 日焼けあとがある人

Comment: All three seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

These can all refer to someone who (currently) has tan lines, and in this sense, they are interchangeable. However, 日焼けあとが残る人 can also refer to someone who gets tan lines (easily) regardless of their current skin tones. For example, 日焼けあとが残る人と残らない人の違い means "the difference between those who (easily) get tan lines and those who don't", and in this case 残る is not interchangeable with the other two.